# May FileOutputStream.getChannel() return null?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I'm analyzing the API for `FileOutputStream`.

Can the `getChannel()` method return `null`? If so, in what situation(s)?

Comment: Did you try it? Did you look into the source code?

Comment: @Tichodroma How would you try that?

Comment: I'm making static analysis of some code. I'm wondering if this situatiom might happen if so then I've bug in software.

Comment: Did you consider reading the Javadoc?

Answer (score 3):

The `FileOutputStream` `getChannel()` method code

```
 public FileChannel getChannel() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (channel == null) {
           channel = FileChannelImpl.open(fd, false, true, this, append);

           /*
             * Increment fd's use count. Invoking the channel's close()
            * method will result in decrementing the use count set for
            * the channel.
             */
            fd.incrementAndGetUseCount();
        }
        return channel;
    }
}
```

calls `FileChannelImpl.open()` and this code always creates a new object

```
public static FileChannel open(FileDescriptor fd,
                                boolean readable, boolean writable,
                                Object parent, boolean append)
 {
    return new FileChannelImpl(fd, readable, writable, parent, append);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public FileChannel getChannel() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (channel == null) {
            channel = FileChannelImpl.open(fd, false, true, append, this);
            fd.incrementAndGetUseCount();
        }
        return channel;
    }
}
```

Shows that `null` cant be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Look to the source of
[FileChannelImpl#open](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/nio/ch/FileChannelImpl.java.html)

method `Open()`
`return new FileChannelImpl(...)`
so it creates new reference, and it cann't be `null`